# Управление глагола "называться"

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, управление, падежи

В каком падеже употребить слово после "называется"? И нужны ли кавычки?

> 1. Он называется Международная система цитогенетической номенклатуры
>      человека (ISCN).
> 2. Это называется мозаичная трисомия по 9 хромосоме.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Назваться** (принять название) ―  творительный падеж. **Называться** (иметь, носить название) ―   именительный падеж. Поэтому возможны различные варианты. **При наличии кавычек** обычно используется именительный падеж (называется, то есть носит название). **Распространенные названия без кавычек** чаще используются в форме творительного падежа.

**Постановка кавычек** также зависит от разных факторов: некоторые названия везде употребляются  в кавычках, в других случаях (это касается сложных составных имен) кавычки ставятся именно в таких предложениях (со словом "называется").

**Можно остановиться на следующем варианте:**

Он называется (носит название) "Международная система цитогенетической номенклатуры человека" (ISCN). Это называется мозаичной трисомией по 9 хромосоме.

**Примеры:**

В 1960 году  была создана первая **Международная система цитогенетической номенклатуры хромосом человека** (нет кавычек). В последующие годы  классификация хромосом человека дорабатывалась и уточнялась и в 2005 г. вышла в новой редакции под названием **«Международная система для цитогенетической номенклатуры человека"** (кавычки ставятся).

Метод называется **«Измерение лучевых скоростей звезд»**. Он называется **межпланетным орбитальным кораблем** (творительный падеж).

**Из словаря:**

НАЗВАТЬСЯ, св. 1. **кем-чем**. Принять, присвоить себе какое-л. название, имя и т.п. Н. защитником угнетённых. Самозванец назвался **царевичем** Дмитрием. * Назвался **груздем** ―  полезай в кузов (Посл.).

НАЗЫВАТЬСЯ, нсв. 1. к Назваться. 2. Иметь, носить какое-л. название, имя. Материал называется **крепдешин**. Конфеты называются **"Белочка".**