# Выделяются ли кавычками разговорные сочетания типа "на [что сделать]"?

Tags: кавычки, рассогласование

Например:

- Он трудоголик, оставляет в сутки себе всего пять-шесть часов *на поспать*.
- Он позвал меня *на поиграть*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строго говоря, в таких случаях нужно использовать кавычки, так как глагол употреблен **в значении существительного**, а такого значения в словаре нет.

Поэтому написание в кавычках **корректно**, можно, наверное, и курсив использовать.

Но сейчас эти сочетания стали **привычными** и чаще пишутся без кавычек, особенно в разговорной речи на форумах. Но и в художественной литературе такое оформление тоже встречается. Возможно, в будущем сочетание будет закреплено в словаре как разговорное.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

— Жена, дети, внуки, бизнес. Приходить ***на поспать***? Не вопрос. [Татьяна Соломатина. Девять месяцев, или «Комедия женских положений» (2010)]

В итоге остается 2 дня ***на поспать*** и, может быть, сексом заняться иногда (все смеются).  «Хулиган», 2004.08.15]

Ему удавалось раскрутить ***на поиграть*** даже зацикленного на компьютерных играх стеснительного 12-летнего мальчика ― к концу вечера бесились только так вместе. [Форум: Компьютерные игры (2012)]

После школы, хоккея и домашнего задания времени вполне хватает ***и на погулять, и на поиграть.*** (Наши дети: Дошколята и младшие школьники. Форум (2005)

Comment: Не хочу отдельный вопрос создавать, спрошу у вас тут, тем более что тема немного похожа. *Этот жанр называется "минимализм". / Этот жанр называется минимализмом*. Верно ли я понимаю, что в первом случае требуются кавычки, а во втором нет? В первом ведь некое рассогласование звучит.

Comment: Помните: …Потому что наша мама Называется — пилот! Хочется сказать — пилотом. Но в принципе у вас верно: Этот жанр называется (чем?)  минимализмом.
Этот жанр называется (имеет название) «минимализм». А вот почему — можно прочитать здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/Управление-глагола-называться  А это примеры с кавычками: Есть такое направление, которое называется "глобальные этимологии". На профессиональном сленге это называется "скамья присяжных". Невыплата долга по векселям не называется громким словом «дефолт».

Comment: Вельми понеже, весьма вами благодарен))

Comment: Да пожалуйста, да для вас-то...

Comment: Курсив используется в лингвистических текстах.

Comment: Укажите источник, что нельзя применять в обычных.  Помнится, Грамота говорила, что Розенталь применяет. И вроде бы всем разрешила, а мне уж точно)

Comment: Да кто говорил, что курсив везде может заменять кавычки? Это полнейший бред. Укажите источник, что можно. У Розенталя столько было бы кавычек (куча примеров, фраз, слов), пришлось использовать что-то другое. Где вы в художественной литературе видели курсив? Это только для лингвистических текстов.

Comment: Совершенно с вами согласна! Полнейший бред-с... В общем, пока. Что вы вообще в этой теме делаете? Ответ принят, автор выразил благодарность. А вы второй уж день допрашиваете меня просто-таки с пристрастием)

Comment: Корректирую вас :)