# Постановка кавычек в зависимости от падежа: есть ли чёткое правило?

Tags: падежи, кавычки, оформление-текста, цитирование

Скажите, насколько уместно ставить кавычки, когда упоминается, что кто-то так-то назвал кого-то? Мне кажется, их можно поставить, если слово в Им. п., а если в других, — не имеет смысла.

*Она не зря назвала его (")утюгом("). Его лицо и правда было каким-то плоским, словно его прогладили, да ещё и красным до жути.*

Думаю, кавычки не нужны, потому что падеж не именительный. Поставил бы кавычки, если бы было в Им. п.: "Она не зря назвала его "утюг"". Не будем же мы закавычивать, если бы было, скажем: "Она не зря назвала его (")дураком(")". Верно? Вот и тут, мне кажется, кавычки излишни для слова "утюгом" ("...назвала его утюгом"). Как вы считаете? Есть какое-то правило универсальное?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила, но толком не объяснив, почему нужны кавычки (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309603)).

Comment: Вопрос уже обсуждался на форуме  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/Управление-глагола-называться   Также посмотрите комментарий  к вопросу https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470908/Выделяются-ли-кавычками-разговорные-сочетания-типа-на-что-сделать/470909?noredirect=1#comment494795_470909 Универсальные правила часто находятся в толковых словарях, почаще туда заглядывайте. Да и само понятие "универсальное правило" звучит странно. Интересно, что вы имеете в виду, какую универсальность?

Comment: Ну, может, лучше "чёткое" правило на этот счёт. То есть насколько строго нужно придерживаться того, что в именительном падеже закавычивать слова надо, а в других не надо.

Comment: Четкое правило на этот счет, конечно, лучше, но у меня нет адреса. Попробуйте найти его сами.