# Нужны ли кавычки после слова «называется»?

Tags: кавычки

Как правильно?

1.1. Это называется «газонокосилка».

1.2. Это называется газонокосилка.

2.1. То, что ты видишь, называется «полукошенный луг, про который кто-то, его кося-таки, забыл».

2.2. То, что ты видишь, называется полукошенный луг, про который кто-то, его кося-таки, забыл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корректное оформление:

1. *Это называется **«газонокосилка»**.* Нет падежного управления.

*Это называется **газонокосилкой**.* Падежное управление, слово общеизвестное (не специальная лексика).

Допускается И.п. без кавычек: Это называется газонокосилка.

2. *То, что ты видишь, называется **«полукошенный луг,** про который кто-то, его кося-таки, забыл»*. Кавычки ставятся при дословном цитировании.

*То, что ты видишь, называется **полукошенным лугом,** про который кто-то, его кося-таки, забыл.*  Нет цитирования.

Тема обсуждалась раньше, например: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/Управление-глагола-называться](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

**Из словаря:**

**НАЗВАТЬСЯ**, св. 1. кем-чем. Принять, присвоить себе какое-л. название, имя и т.п. Н. защитником угнетённых. Самозванец назвался царевичем Дмитрием. * Назвался груздем ― полезай в кузов (Посл.).

**НАЗЫВАТЬСЯ**, нсв. 1. к Назваться. 2. Иметь, носить какое-л. название, имя. Материал называется крепдешин. Конфеты называются "Белочка".

Comment: А можно правило? Мне кажется, что и именительный можно без кавычек.

Comment: Можно такое:  https://popravilam.com/blog/017-eshhe-o-kavychkax.html  Вот еще http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2659963-stavjatsja-li-kavychki-posle-nazyvaetsja-znachit.html     ПАС по ред. Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

Comment: У Лопатина другое (цитаты, а не названия).

Comment: Потому что наша мама называется пилот.  Это разговорная речь. Материалы форума:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/Управление-глагола-называться   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470908/Выделяются-ли-кавычками-разговорные-сочетания-типа-на-что-сделать/470909?noredirect=1#comment494795_470909    https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470958/Постановка-кавычек-в-зависимости-от-падежа-есть-ли-чёткое-правило

Comment: Хотелось правило...

Comment: Не вам одним)) Другим тоже хотелось. Найдете – вашим будет! ))

Comment: Моим точно не будет от этого)

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что допускается? :)

Comment: Словарь читайте, там все написано.

Comment: То есть кавычки можно, но это необязательно?

Comment: Да, если мы используем И.п., то привычные названия лучше писать без кавычек, а кавычки больше подходят для менее известных слов, а также собственных имен, как в словаре: Материал называется крепдешин. Конфеты называются "Белочка".

Comment: "Крепдешин" известное слово?)

Comment: Нет – и точно нет!