# Согласование приложения

Tags: приложение

Я пришел с собакой Волчок?
Я пришел с собакой Волчком?
Как будет правильно и почему?

Comment: Вот придёт к тебе Волчок и укусит за бочок. А потом окажется, что это самый настоящий волчара с маленькой буквы!)))

Comment: Артем, а в стихах было бы еще лучше!

Comment: Верно, Sharon, только из меня поэт как из лягушки королева. :))

Comment: Запятая перед "как из лягушки королева" не нужна, т.к. оборот с союзом КАК является сказуемым?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: **Я пришел **с собакой Волчком**.**

***Собака*** — определяемое существительное, ***Волчок*** — приложение.

Это классический вид приложения, которое определяется как **согласование в падеже двух склоняемых существительных**, одно из которых является определением (приложением). Тематика данного варианта — **кличка животного**.

В каждой теме (а их несколько) встречаются **несклоняемые приложения**, но в данном случае это возможно **для двух вариантов**:

(1) не склоняется сама кличка (например, *Долли*): *Я пришел с собакой **Долли**.*

(2) используется оборот "по кличке": Я *пришел с собакой **по кличке Волчок**.*

P.S.

Тема дана по книге **"Русская грамматика" под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина,** 1990 год, 2-е издание. Ее часто называют "Краткой Русской грамматикой" (там только один том), но найти книгу онлайн у меня не получается. В частности тема "Приложения" изложена там коротко и по существу.

Comment: Шерон. А есть ли какие-то случаи, когда приложение будет неизменяемым (не собственное), при этом оно не будет считаться несклоняемым в обычной ситуации (слова в кавычках в расчет не берем)?

Comment: В "Краткой Русской грамматике"  указана такая группа. При большой слитности признака с предметом приложения (обычно препозитивные) теряют способность к словоизменению и ведут себя как сложные слова: бой-баба, горе-охотник, чудо-дерево, жар-птица, царь-колокол.

Comment: Также надо отличать сложные слова плащ-палатка, шеф-повар от составных наименований, которые склоняются: платье-костюм, ковер-самолет, диван-кровать, вагон-ресторан. Их желательно проверять по словарю, возможны колебания.

Comment: Но здесь везде речь о дефисных написаниях. А если, например, жанр рецензия. Можно ли написать он пишет в жанре "рецензия" без кавычек или будет считаться ошибкой?

Comment: В интернете есть АГ-80.

Comment: @Ajgy  А это уже конкуренция родо-видовых отношений и Р.п в качестве определения. Давайте оставим эту тему за мной. Помню, я отвечала на такой вопрос, надо поискать. Ответ там неоднозначный.

Comment: @Серж  АГ-80 есть в Сети (два тома), но там по приложениям меньше материала, чем в однотомнике.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на комментарий:** *А если, например, жанр рецензия. Можно ли написать: он пишет в жанре "рецензия" без кавычек или будет считаться ошибкой?*

**1. Родо-видовые названия**

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Два нарицательных существительных, выражающих **родовое и видовое понятия** в классификации природных объектов, пишутся раздельно. Ср.: *птица иволга, рыба треска, дерево ольха, цветок роза, минерал лазурит, металл литий.*

Вероятно, аналогично пишутся и другие родовые и видовые понятия: ***жанр рецензия.***

**2. Родо-видовые названия в падежной форме**

Например, участника, выступавшего в жанре пародия, мы попросили исполнить трагический номер.  Нужно кавычить "пародия"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Лучше: _...выступавшего **в жанре пародии.**
Грамота фактически уходит от ответа про кавычки и **везде рекомендует Р.п.**

**3. Смежная тема: Управление глагола "называться"**
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470908/Выделяются-ли-кавычками-разговорные-сочетания-типа-на-что-сделать](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470908/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Вопрос задан в комментариях: **Этот жанр называется "минимализм". / Этот жанр называется минимализмом.** Верно ли я понимаю, что в первом случае требуются кавычки, а во втором нет? В первом ведь некое рассогласование звучит.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/Управление-глагола-называться](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429743/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Comment: То есть рекомендуется писать в родительном падеже всегда? Например, я знаком с жанром рецензии?

Comment: Здесь однозначных правил нет, поэтому желательно ориентироваться на практику речи. Если у нас два слова в И.п. (жанр рецензии), то знака между ними нет, это родо-видовые отношения. Если второе слово распространено, то его лучше поставить в форме Р.п., кавычки обычно не используются.  Кавычки ставятся, если название длинное. Все это можно посмотреть в Нацкорпусе для слова "жанр". Например: жанр научной фантастики, жанр сказок, жанр полемики, диалога, интервью. Или поискать рекомендации Грамоты.